# NSIS Alternative If, then, else, andif etc

Tags: if-statement, nsis

My question is if there is an alternative plugin similar to LogicLib? One that does support numbers like `17.0.8.22` since my program version that's in the registry is a number like that and it seems like LogicLib does not support this for Windows 7.
It does recgonize it like this:

```
${If} $0 = '17.0.22.0'
```

But this is failing/being ignored,

```
${If} $0 > '17.0.22.0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Anders states, the `VersionCompare` macro can handle complex version comparison.

Here is a little example:

```
!include "logiclib.nsh"
!include "wordfunc.nsh"
OutFile "version.exe"

!define v1 "1.4.0"
!define v2 "1.3"

Section

    ${VersionCompare} "${v1}" "${v2}" $0
    ${select} $0
        ${case} 0
            messagebox MB_OK "${v1} = ${v2}"
        ${case} 1
            messagebox MB_OK "${v1} newer than ${v2}"
        ${case} 2
            messagebox MB_OK "${v1} older than ${v2}"
    ${endselect}

SectionEnd
```

Comment: @YoshiKlarenbeek: Could you elaborate? I cannot understand what embedded installer you are talking about. Note that my example is using  hard coded versions via defines, but you can use any other variables.

Comment: I am using NSIS to make a setup that installs an app called TT. This program needs a program called VDF in order to run properly. So I included the installer of VDF in the $EXEDIR. So that the Installer of TT can read the registry to check whether version 17.0.22.8 is installed. If this or a newer version is installed it should give a MBox saying `Attention, VDF is already installed on this machine.` And it cancels the execution of the embed installer, If the version that currently is installed on the machine is lower or it's not able to find it it should execute the embedded installer.

Comment: @YoshiKlarenbeek: From here, I do not see any problem. Make a similar test between the registry saved version and the one that you will define in your script; if the returned value is 1 (older) start your embedded setup else (for 0 and 2) show a message box. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Well I am a little bit further now, after a weekend of great distraction my mind is fresh for new challenges however it is giving me 1 weird issue, check out this [screenshot.](http://www.upload.ee/image/2681040/hwlp.png)

Answer (score 1):

[VersionCompare](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#versioncompare) is a part of the helper macros that ship with NSIS...

Comment: That's all very nice, but I need it to check whether the current value is higher or lower or the same as 17.0.22.8 so when the current value is lower or it doesn't exists then it need to do something.

Comment: What's the problem? Depending on the value that is returned by VersionCompare, you can handle the 3 alternatives (older / same / newer).